# Is it ok to use Laravel Auth in react or vue?

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, jwt

Oauth, JWT auth(api authentication - no browser dependency) are used in a SPA environment. But Laravel auth (session authentication - saving laravel cookies in client browsers) also works well in a SPA environment. There are no problems with using session authentications in react or vue based SPA environments, as the reason that we use an api authentication is just for non-browser environments.

XMLhttprequest(ajax) is not related to whether to use api or session authentication, as laravel auth cookies are attached when the xmlhttprequest is sent.

However, Laravel react or vue developers seem to use only Oauth or JWT auth... no?

Comment: if you have the app on the same domain with the laravel then you can use cookies, Oauth and JWT are used when you don't have the app on the same domain with the laravel installation

Comment: Right. CORS is one reason to use an api authentication.

Comment: you can't share a cookie between domains

Comment: We should use tokens injected in headers or as just parameters in such the cross-domain situation. But my project is just in the same domain. I just don't know why people prefer JWT auth to Laravel sessions in react or vue projects. SPA(Single Page Application) using React or vue is not related to cross-domain situations, is it?

Comment: I am also aware that cookies are not available between domains.

Comment: There's little to no benefit in using OAuth or JWT to communicate between your server-side and client side of the same web application since cookies (and the session) are pretty good at achieving the same result. You should use JWT or OAuth if you intend to (at some point) open up your back end to 3rd parties though.